# How to catch "The system cannot find the file" within For /F loop?

Tags: batch-file, batch, windows-command-prompt, batch-processing

How to catch "The system cannot find the file" within `For /F loop`?

I would like my code to do the following:

- 1 - Search for the specified file
- 2 - If file not found, handle the "The system cannot find the file"
  by sleeping for 10 seconds and repeating the search
- 3 - If the file is found (it will be added to the directory
  eventually), continue with the script

Current code for search:

```
FOR /F "tokens=* delims=" %%x IN (D:\batch\logs\mylog_%1.log) DO (
       SET content=%%x & ECHO !content!
)
```

`%1` is my input parameter once called via .bat script

Comment: :LOG_CHECK
IF EXIST D:\batch\logs\mylog_%1.log (GOTO START_LOOP) ELSE (TIMEOUT /T 10 /NOBREAK)
GOTO LOG_CHECK

REM Restart label
:START_LOOP

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

```
:LOG_CHECK

IF EXIST D:\batch\logs\mylog_%1.log (
    GOTO START_LOOP
) ELSE (
    TIMEOUT /T 10 /NOBREAK
)
GOTO LOG_CHECK

REM Restart label
:START_LOOP  
REM my code continues with processes
```